# find size of union of two sets?

Tags: c++, set, set-union

Is there any way to find size of union of two sets.
I know can do this

```
vector < int > s3( s1.size() , s2.size() ); 
auto it=set_union( s1.begin() , s1.end() , s2.begin() ,s2.end(), s3.begin());
int size = it - s3.begin();
```

print size

**example**

```
s1 = {2 4 5 6}   size 4

s2 = {1 4 5 9 10}  size 5

s3 = {1 2 4 5 6 9 10}  size 7

complexity of set_union is 2*(s1 size + s2 size)-1
```

**Is there any other method to get size of union of two sets faster method, I just need the size do not  want the values of new union set formed.
If you know a faster method please suggest.**

Comment: If the method I stated is the only method possible please tell that too.

Comment: How could one work out the size of a set without knowing the contents of the set? Guess work perhaps

Comment: s1 and s2 are already known s3 is using space and time both any this be reduced

Comment: Please explain your comment

Comment: Reference from where I studied-> http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_union/


I am trying to solve a question that on requires size of union set formed.

with set_union I am utilizing space and time both.
I am getting a TLE for that question so I thought may be there is a better method to find size of set.

Comment: You could iterate over both sets for an O(n) solution with no extra space. Would that be good enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just put a counting iterator in last argument to set_union. E.g.

```
int count = 0;
it=set_union( s1.begin() , s1.end() , s2.begin() ,s2.end(), boost::make_function_output_iterator([&count](int){ ++count; }));
```

Or a non-boost equivalent of that output iterator

```
struct counter {
    using difference_type = void;
    using value_type = void;
    using pointer = void;
    using reference = void;
    using iterator_category = std::output_iterator_tag;
    int count = 0;
    void operator&(int) { ++count }
    counter& operator++ { return *this; }
};
```

Comment: OP hasn't tagged this question as [tag:boost], so I would at least specify, that the answer is [tag:boost] only.

Comment: I've given an example of expanding the lambda into that template manually

Answer (score 0):

One obvious way is to perform the same iteration `set_union` does but instead of copying the elements, just bump up a counter. That leaves the time complexity unchanged but eshews space usage completely.

Theoretically, one could devise an `OutputIterator` that just counts the elements so that `set_union` algorithm could be reused. Whether that is worth the hassle of making your iterator quack exactly the way STL expects it to is a different question... Reimplementing `set_union` to do just counting might be easier.